# Ruby I/O: Rails rake task is trying to find and replace certain lines of code, but doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a rake task that changes the meta tags for certain pages.  These tags are defined in the controller. The rake task is meant to open the controller file, find any line with the phrase "@meta_tag" in it, and then re-write that line per the replace_line(line) method.  When I run the rake task, I don't get any errors, but it also doesn't make any changes.

I think my problem is in the 'r+' line.  Do I need to open the file in one line and write to it in another line of code?

```
require 'rake'
namespace :meta_tags do
  desc 'changes the meta tags'
  task :update => :environment do 

    regex = /@meta_tag/
    found = false
    file = File.open('app/controllers/site_controller.rb', 'r+')
    file.each_line do |line|
      replace_line(line) if(found)
      found = true if(line =~ regex)
    end
  end

  def replace_line(line)
    meta_tags = MetaTag.all.map { |tag| tag["tag"] }
    new_tag = meta_tags.sample(1)[0]
    line = "@meta_tag = #{new_tag}"
  end
end
```

If you see what I'm doing wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you don't actually write to the file anywhere. `each_line` does just what it says, it iterates over each line in the file (actually it reads until there is a newline and then yields this line to the block you provide).

But just using `file.write` now isn't a really good idea since **inplace** file-writing doesn't work like you would expect. Because files are byte/character based, a replacementline would have to be exactly as long as the old one.

So you should go with the normally used practice of *reading then writing*. Also your current code would alter the line **after** the
`@meta_tag` occurrence, although your question suggests that this is not what
you want.
Here is an example applied to your situation:

```
require 'rake'
namespace :meta_tags do
  desc 'changes the meta tags'
    task :update => :environment do 

    regex = /@meta_tag/
    # only 'r' since you will only read the file,
    # although you could use 'r+' and just change the lineno
    # back to 0 when finished reading...
    file = File.open('app/controllers/site_controller.rb', 'r')
    lines = []
    file.each_line do |line|
      # i don't think you need the found variable,
      # it is simple if-then/else
      (line =~ regex) ? (lines << replace_line(line)) : (lines << line)
    end
    file.close
    file = File.open('app/controllers/site_controller.rb', 'w')
    # you could also join the array beforehand,
    # and use one big write-operation,
    # i don't know which approach would be faster...
    lines.each{|line| file.write line} 
    file.close
  end

  def replace_line(line)
    meta_tags = MetaTag.all.map { |tag| tag["tag"] }
    new_tag = meta_tags.sample(1)[0]
    line = "@meta_tag = #{new_tag}\n" # added the newline
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow.  You are a wealth of information!  Thank you for going the extra mile and cranking out a working version!  How did you get so knowledgeable about this I/O stuff?  If you found any resources that greatly helped you, I'd love to know.

Comment: well any in-depth book on almost any programming language will provide this sort of information. i learned most of the io-stuff from an in-depth C book (kind of forgot the name) and well trying, testing and trying... ;)